# Electron app in production mode fails to run external script via child_process.spawnSync API in Mac but works perfectly in Linux

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

The app computes the sum of the exponentials of the two entered integers using an R code. The inputs are passed in the form of a JSON object to the R code via child_process.spawnSync API of node.js.

The app was packaged using electron-packager(v15.2.0) and its structure is as shown in the screenshot below. Source code to reproduce this issue can be obtained from this GitHub folder: https://github.com/wasimaftab/Utils/tree/master/test_js_r_interaction

[image]

index.js file contains the code to interact with R. Important note, **you need to install rjson R package before attempting to run the electron app** as it is used in R to extract the arguments from json object.
In Ubuntu (18.04) the output as expected, see the screenshot below,

[image]

**The same code fails in Mac (Catalina 10.15.7) after packaging but, works perfectly in development mode**, see the screenshot below.

[image]

The actual error is as follows:

```
Error: spawnSync Rscript ENOENT
    at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1041:20)
    at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:625:24)
    at callSync (file:///Users/admin/Desktop/test_js_r_interaction/release-builds-mac/test_js_r_interaction-darwin-x64/test_js_r_interaction.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/index.js:25:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (file:///Users/admin/Desktop/test_js_r_interaction/release-builds-mac/test_js_r_interaction-darwin-x64/test_js_r_interaction.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/index.js:84:20)
```

and the js code to interact with R is as follows:

```
const path = require("path");

const child_process = require('child_process');

const RSCRIPT = 'Rscript';

const defaultOptions = {
    verboseResult: false
}

function parseStdout(output) {
    try {
        output = output.substr(output.indexOf('"{'), output.lastIndexOf('}"'));
        return JSON.parse(JSON.parse(output));
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}

function callSync(script, args, options) {
    options = options || defaultOptions;

    const result = args ?
        child_process.spawnSync(RSCRIPT, [script, JSON.stringify(args)]) :
        child_process.spawnSync(RSCRIPT, [script]);

    if (result.status == 0) {
        const ret = parseStdout(result.stdout.toString());
        if (!(ret instanceof Error)) {
            if (options.verboseResult) {
                return {
                    pid: result.pid,
                    result: ret
                };
            } else {
                return ret;
            };
        } else {
            return {
                pid: result.pid,
                error: ret.message
            };
        }
    } else if (result.status == 1) {
        return {
            pid: result.pid,
            error: result.stderr.toString()
        };
    } else {
        return {
            pid: result.pid,
            error: result.stderr.toString()
            //error: result.stdout.toString()
        };
    }
}
```

I will appreciate any suggestion to fix this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: Just a side note: Any status > 0 typically specifies that an error occurred and the program did not finish successfully. Thus, I'd recommend to better use `stderr` in your `else` block (from which the error originates). Btw., please [edit] your question to contain the relevant portions of your code (specifically `callSync`) and also a text representation of the error you're experiencing (generally, don't solely rely on photos of errors or code please). Links, both to code and images, may become invalid which would render your question incomprehensible to future readers.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thanks for your time, I have now included the actual error in the text and the JS code that is used to interact with R.

Comment: I have a similar problem and found from my own observation, that it is probably something to do with not being able to read or write from a packaged `.app` executable.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting, `ENOENT`, suggests that your OS cannot find `Rscript`. This can result from the following scenarios:

1. `Rscript` is not even installed.
2. `Rscript` is installed, but not executable without a "shell". To check whether it is installed, open a Terminal and execute the command as your Electron application would.

If `Rscript` can be executed from within a Terminal, there could be something wrong with how the installation has set your paths up. There shouldn't be, really, but it might be necessary to execute `spawnSync` with additional options, such as `{ shell: true }` to get the correct value of `PATH`.

If `Rscript` cannot be executed from within a Terminal, forcing Electron to spawn a shell via the above options (which really is what a Terminal does) will not solve this problem. In this case, try to use the complete path to `Rscript` as the `command` instead, if you happen to know where it should be installed.

If neither of those solutions help, try reinstalling `Rscript` altogether and try again. As I can see nothing which would be wrong with your code, I believe it is a problem of installation.

For more information on `child_process.spawnSync (command, args, options)`, see [its documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I found that app only works with the full path to Rscript. But the problem is that for other pc this may not work so I tried npm `which` function to systematically discover the Rscript path but it failed to do so in production mode. I have edited the question with screenshots to clarify this issue.

Comment: Well, does `{ shell: true }` change anything? Or does it really only work with the full path? Theoretically, appending `{ shell: true }` should basically behave the same as the Terminal app. If not (and if your issue with the `which` module persists), I suggest that you revert your edit to your question and ask a new one (since the two issues are unrelated).

Comment: when I use `'child_process.spawnSync(RSCRIPT, [script, JSON.stringify(args)],{ shell: true }) :
        child_process.spawnSync(RSCRIPT, [script], { shell: true });` I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exp_sum' of undefined` in developement mode itself but with full path no error in both production and development mode.

Comment: OK then. This, however, indicates yet another problem which deserves its own question, to be honest. It seems as though the R process finishes correctly but does not provide the output you're expecting. If you also want to get the "workaround" with `which` to work, I suggest to ask a new question regarding this phenomenon. Either way, decide on which solution to pursue and link your new question to this one. I believe that this answer solves your problem in the first place, but new problems arose from this "solution". Anyhow, doing this debugging through comments is not the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I do not think the R process finishes correctly in production mode because the js code is unable to discover it. That's why it crashes.